# Java Hibernate fetch not working correctly

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a Spring Resource Service with Spring JPA and Hibernate.
I have defined some entities with ManyToMany relationships.
As long as I know, ManyToMany and OneToMany relationshios has LAZY fetch. Even that I have defined them for LAZY fetching.

The problem comes when I try get a property of an object (`explotacion.getMaquinas()`), Hibernate execute all queryes to get all the object properties, even the marked with LAZY fetching and after that, it tries to reload the main entity ftrying to find it by the property I have tried to get.
Finally it returns me an empty property because the entity has not loaded the property I am trying to get.

I think that this problem is known as the N+1 query problem but has no clue how to solve it.
Here comes the code:

Explotacion class:

```
package ...;

import java.util.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Explotacion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "explotacion", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Cultivo> cultivos;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "explotaciones", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Maquina> maquinas; 



    // Entidades referenciadas

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "explotaciones", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Usuario> usuarios;
}
```

Maquina class:

```
package ...;

import java.util.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Maquina {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;



    // Entidades referenciadas

    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "maquina_explotacion",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "maquina_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "explotacion_id"))
    private Set<Explotacion> explotaciones;
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=5050

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/databaseName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = *******

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

#Turn Statistics on and log SQL stmts
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true



# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

# Custom H2 Console URLS
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console



#If want to see very extensive logging
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
```

pom.xml (maven dependencies):

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>*****</groupId>
    <artifactId>*****</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>*****</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Terminal output when debugging:

On executing

```
Optional<Explotacion> explotacion = explotacionRepository.findById(id);
```

Terminal output:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        e1_0.id,
        e1_0.nombre
    from
        explotacion e1_0
    where
        e1_0.id=?
```

Later on executing:

```
Explotacion explotacionAux = explotacion.get();
Set<Maquina> maquinasAsociadas = explotacionAux.getMaquinas();
```

Terminal output:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        m1_0.explotacion_id,
        m1_1.id,
        m1_1.nombre
    from
        maquina_explotacion m1_0
    join
        maquina m1_1
            on m1_1.id=m1_0.maquina_id
    where
        m1_0.explotacion_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        e1_0.maquina_id,
        e1_1.id,
        e1_1.nombre
    from
        maquina_explotacion e1_0
    join
        explotacion e1_1
            on e1_1.id=e1_0.explotacion_id
    where
        e1_0.maquina_id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        c1_0.explotacion_id,
        c1_0.id,
        c1_0.nombre,
        c1_0.superficie,
        c1_0.variedad_id,
        v1_0.id,
        v1_0.codigo_especie,
        v1_0.codigo_variedad,
        v1_0.descripcion,
        v1_0.especie
    from
        cultivo c1_0
    left join
        variedad v1_0
            on v1_0.id=c1_0.variedad_id
    where
        c1_0.explotacion_id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        m1_0.explotacion_id,
        m1_1.id,
        m1_1.nombre
    from
        maquina_explotacion m1_0
    join
        maquina m1_1
            on m1_1.id=m1_0.maquina_id
    where
        m1_0.explotacion_id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        u1_0.explotacion_id,
        u1_1.id,
        u1_1.apellido1,
        u1_1.apellido2,
        a1_0.usuario_id,
        a1_0.authorities,
        u1_1.enabled,
        u1_1.expired_account,
        u1_1.expired_credentials,
        u1_1.locked,
        u1_1.nif,
        u1_1.nombre,
        u1_1.password,
        u1_1.username
    from
        usuario_explotacion u1_0
    join
        usuario u1_1
            on u1_1.id=u1_0.usuario_id
    left join
        usuario_authorities a1_0
            on u1_1.id=a1_0.usuario_id
    where
        u1_0.explotacion_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        a1_0.usuario_id,
        a1_0.authorities
    from
        usuario_authorities a1_0
    where
        a1_0.usuario_id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        e1_0.usuario_id,
        e1_1.id,
        e1_1.nombre
    from
        usuario_explotacion e1_0
    join
        explotacion e1_1
            on e1_1.id=e1_0.explotacion_id
    where
        e1_0.usuario_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.explotacion_id,
        u1_1.id,
        u1_1.apellido1,
        u1_1.apellido2,
        a1_0.usuario_id,
        a1_0.authorities,
        u1_1.enabled,
        u1_1.expired_account,
        u1_1.expired_credentials,
        u1_1.locked,
        u1_1.nif,
        u1_1.nombre,
        u1_1.password,
        u1_1.username
    from
        usuario_explotacion u1_0
    join
        usuario u1_1
            on u1_1.id=u1_0.usuario_id
    left join
        usuario_authorities a1_0
            on u1_1.id=a1_0.usuario_id
    where
        u1_0.explotacion_id=?
```

Finally the result on `getMaquinas()` returns an empty Set.

I have researched on many posts and pages looking for the root of the problem. I think my class definitions are ok but may be there is something wrong in my configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entities have `@Data` annotation. It generates `equals`/`hashCode` methods which use all fields including associations. And you are using `Set` for `maquinas`, which calls those `equals`/`hashCode`. So it causes the lazy fields initialization.

Try to replace `@Data` with `@Getter` and `@Setter`. You can read more about that problem in this post https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/